# How to highlight all matched word in single snippet in solr

Tags: solr, highlight

All:

Right now, I am using SOLR highlight feature, but one thing I want to ask is:

Suppose I want to search keyword fund and value:

```
fund AND value
```

And the return highlight part is like:

```
"highlighting": {
    "blk_0019": {
      "content": [
        "philosophy of the <em>fund</em> – <em>value</em> and turning point. \n \n MUSA was an orphaned"
      ]
    },
    "blk_0006": {
      "content": [
        "Global Equities <em>Fund</em> Ltd. \n \n CONFIDENTIAL enclosed"
      ]
    }
}
```

The problem is I am sure blk_0019 and blk_0006 have both fund and value(obviously I use fund AND report), because the I set hl.fragsize=100, if the fund and value located not close enough in one document, they can not be shown both in same snippet. In blk_0019, solr highlights both fund and value, but in blk_0006, only fund shown.

**How can I show both matched in single snippet and just ignore text between them as ..... like in Google**

Also some small questions are:

> [1] How to specify to search capitalized only  word like Hello HELLO
> in Solr?
>
> [2] How to search All-capital AND(All-capital "AND" will be consider as logical operator)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the highlighter you are using. For the Standard Highlighter you can set `hl.snippets=5` for instance (default is 1). Then you'll get 5 snippets/fragments (at most), each with a maximum length of `hl.fragsize`.

They're returned as multiple values, so you'll need to join them yourself (using "..." for instance).

Comment: Thanks for help. There is one question I am wondering: How can I arrange the priority of highlight results? Suppose I want to search: +Fund OR (value USA), it seems +Fund is a very important keyword and I definitively want to show its match in highlight result, but if the matched location in the document is beyond hl.snippets, it may not shown in the results, HOW CAN I configure to make sure Fund match result can always in the result?

Comment: Good question. Maybe you should have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Postings+Highlighter. It focusses on good summarizes by scoring the "passages" (as the fragements are called in this context). But be warned, it works completely differently.

Comment: Thanks, I study on that. Could you help me with another question about solr query syntax? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865771/beginner-about-solr-boolean-operation-like-combination-of-and-or

Comment: Could you tell me where in your answer did you explain the solution to question [2]How to search All-capital AND(All-capital "AND" will be consider as logical operator)

Comment: Boolean operators can be escaped in Solr using "\", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890401