# How to match capitalized/all-uppercase/all-lowercased word in Regular expression

Tags: regex

All:

As title.

How to make word pattern like Hello/HELLO/hello

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([A-Za-z][a-z]*|[A-Z]+)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZ0cV1/1)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. A basic question about | sign, is it a OR operation between [a-z]* and [A-Z]+, or it operate between [A-Za-z][a-z]* and [A-Z]+

Comment: `|` is alternation between `[A-Za-z][a-z]*` and `[A-Z]+`

Comment: Could you help me with a not quite related problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849659/how-to-highlight-all-matched-word-in-single-snippet-in-solr

Comment: So sorry for interrupting. See ya later.

Comment: Looked at your other question, sorry I don't know anything about `solr`.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will just keep searching.